# Programmatically Set UIImage Animation with WatchKit in Swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I can't seem to figure out how to programmatically animate UIImages.

I've seen a code written in Objective-C, but looking for a solution in Swift.

The closest code I can find is:

```
imageView.startAnimatingWithImages(in: ???[NSRange] , duration: 1, repeatCount: 100)
```

but I'm not sure what to put in NSRange. Images is stored in my asset folder in a folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHAw3.png)

Code in swift(but not for Apple Watch): [How to animate images in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584729/how-to-animate-images-in-swift)

Objective- C code: [Programatically Set UIImage Animation with WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681267/programatically-set-uiimage-animation-with-watchkit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a swift solution: quiet simple, I just needed to add an image outlet and write the following two code items:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageObject: WKInterfaceImage!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        imageObject.setImageNamed("plank")
        imageObject.startAnimating()
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }
}
```